# Debug React Native app on iPhone with VSCode

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode installed on Ubuntu with React Native Tools 0.4.1 installed. I can't figure out how to use debug with it. Tried to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_MnXPD55-E) tutorial with no luck - it just stacks on loading and nothing happens.

My launch.json is created automatically and looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Android",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "iPhone 5s",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
}
```